# Get language from Shared Prefences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to save the current language in a variable to use it in an other page. I'm using shared_preferences with flutter_translate.

In my app.dart I have this :

```
class TranslatePreferences implements ITranslatePreferences
{
  static const String _selectedLocaleKey = 'selected_locale';

  @override
  Future<Locale> getPreferredLocale() async
  {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if(!preferences.containsKey(_selectedLocaleKey)) return null;

    var locale = preferences.getString(_selectedLocaleKey);
    return localeFromString(locale);

  }


  @override
  Future savePreferredLocale(Locale locale) async
  {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setString(_selectedLocaleKey, localeToString(locale));

  }


}
```

If I print :

```
print(TranslatePreferences().getPreferredLocale());
```

I get : `Instance of 'Future<Locale>'`

How I can manage it to get the value of the getPreferredLocale() and store in a variable ?

Thanks

Comment: `await TranslatePreferences().getPreferredLocale()` : https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: I get the value in the print in this way : Current() async {
  TranslatePreferences().getPreferredLocale();

  var a=await TranslatePreferences().getPreferredLocale();

  return a;

}

but when I print(Current()); I get this : Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

How I get return the value ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Future<String> futureValue = Future.value("Hello !");
```

Print future value in **sync**

```
void main() {
  futureValue.then((value) => print(value)); // Hello !
}
```

Print future value in **async**

```
void main() async {
  final value = await futureValue;
  print(value); // Hello !
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it but how I can get the value out of the main ?

Comment: You can only get values asynchronously.

Comment: I have to launch all my app in the void, you mean ?

Comment: No ,  please watch this : https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await