# How to solve SharedPreferences not working in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using SharedPreferences to save the response from API. I want to use when my apps is offline or switch to another tab, the data will not reload again. But it not working. It only working when I online. But if I online I switch the page the data will reload again. If I offline the data will not come out.

Comment: Can you post you sample json data.

Comment: thank you for your reply, {"current_page": 1, 
"data": [ 
    { "id": 1, "title": "Germa","image": "image url"}, 
    { "id": 2, "title": "Jepun", "image": "image url"} 
    ], 
 "first_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=1", 
 "from": 1, 
 "last_page": 30, 
 "last_page_url": "https:/API_URLpage=30", 
 "next_page_url": "https:/API_URL?page=2"
}

Answer (score 0):

Ruturn the data in finally :

```
Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  try {
    // your codes ...
  } finally {
    String myDataValue = prefs.getString('myData');
    return pagesDataFromJson(myDataValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: I try this, but it will show the CacheManager: Failed to download file from URL and will repeat load the page 1 data only.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I see that when you are online you get the data and it gets parsed, but when you are offline and you are doing all the stuff in the try-catch block, so when you go offline there is socket Exception that occurs in a catch block that you have not handled.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String myDataValue = prefs.getString('myData');
        final project = pagesDataFromJson(myDataValue);
```

if you call this in the catch you might be able to get the data when you are offline.

But this is just a fix check this link which will tell you if internet is there or no :
https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker

or youcan refer this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_Xyqo6lhFE

So it would not load the data from the prefrences because when you get the exception it directly goes to the catch without leaving the below code.

Comment: thank you for your reply, now if I offline I get error about the CacheManager: Failed to download file from URL and will repeat load the page 1 data only

Comment: yeah, its because you are offline and you are trying to make a network request maybe I suggest you check Internet connection using the above described package ,if not show the dummy image.

Comment: but why it only show page 1 data?  The title in page 1 still showing when I am offline. but it always repeat and repeat the page 1 only

Comment: did not get you? can you breif

Comment: Just got you what you are saying, the reason you are using the pagination and it has loaded only one-page data and now there is no connection, so next page data will not come.

Comment: I have using flutter_offline package, so I can check is online or offline. My json response is data in pagination. So, When I offline, I can only get the page 1 detail but it will always loop the page 1 detail only

Comment: Is have the way to show page 2 also when I am offline

Comment: Maybe using the local databases you can achieve this thing. or i don't prefer this but you just load all the at once . create a method that will fetch all the data.

Comment: sharedpreferences not local database?

Comment: it's local storage but temporary, you cannot save too much data. As per the standard.

Comment: the only way is to save in the local database?

Comment: If you want to follow the standard then use databases, or(time being solution) you can create a method that loads the data based on the last page. using the for loop you limiting it to last page length and the make an API call and add all the objects in the list. so when later when you go offline you can use it. But at first, you should be online.

Comment: If you think that this answers was helpful then you can make a checkmark and a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data from the API

```
Future<String> fetchPagesData(int page) {
  String url = Uri.encodeFull("https://API_URL?page=$page");
  return http.get(url).body;
}
```

Set `SharedPreferences` data

```
Future<String> setPagesData(int page, String value) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('myData$page', value);
}
```

Get `SharedPreferences` data

```
Future<PagesData> getPagesData(int page) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('myData$page');
}
```

Catch while offline

```
Future<PagesData> sendPagesDataRequest(int page) async {
  try {
    fetchPagesData(page).then((value) => setPagesData(page, value));
//   } on SocketException {
// no network connection   
  } catch (e) {}

  return getPagesData(page);
}
```

Comment: at getPagesData have error about:  A value of type 'String can't be returned from method 'getPagesData' because it has a return type of 'Future<PagesData>'.

Comment: You can only get values asynchronously.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450415/get-language-from-shared-prefences-in-flutter